# Training TensorFlow for Predicting a Column in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, tensorflow

I have data that is structured in a csv file. I want to be able to predict whether column 1 is going to be a 1 or a 0 given all other columns. How do I go about training the program (preferably using Neural Networks) to use all of the given data in order to make that prediction. Is there code that someone can show me? I've tried feeding it `numpy.ndarray`, `FIF0Que` (sorry if I spelt that wrong), and a `DataFrame`; nothing has worked yet. Here is the code I am running until I get the error-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 11])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([11,2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,2])

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = data.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

At which point I run into this error-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-b48741faa01b> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(1000):
----> 2     batch_xs, batch_ys = data.train.next_batch(100)
      3     sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'train'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. All I need to do is predict whether column 1 is going to be a 1 or a 0. Even if all you do is get me past this one error, I should be able to take it from there.

EDIT: This is what the csv looks like when I print it out.

```
[[1,0.766126609,45,2,0.802982129,9120,13,0,6,0,2],
[0,0.957151019,40,0,0.121876201,2600,4,0,0,0,1],
[0,0.65818014,38,1,0.085113375,3042,2,1,0,0,0],
[0,0.233809776,30,0,0.036049682,3300,5,0,0,0,0]]
```

I'm trying to predict the first column.

Comment: You are mixing up the tutorial with numpy genfromtxt.   data.train is from input_data.py

check input_data.py  https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py

It creates the "train" attribute that you're re-using from the example.  Numpy arrays do not have train attributes (which is what genfromtxt returns).

Comment: I've tried to pull some insight from the source code but haven't gotten much further with it. I think I need to turn it into a DataSet (input_data.DataSets) but I don't know how to do it. I removed all of the labels and the row markers as well.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. This is good stuff

Comment: Oh there will be plenty more questions from me on TensorFlow O.rka. I'm going to learn this. I've been playing around with it for days now.

Answer (score 5):

The following reads from a CSV file and builds a tensorflow program. The example uses the Iris data set, since that maybe a more meaningful example. However, it should probably work for your data as well.

Please note, the first column will be [0,1 or 2], since there are 3 species of iris.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

# Build Example Data is CSV format, but use Iris data
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import sklearn
def buildDataFromIris():
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    f=open('cs-training.csv','w')
    for i,j in enumerate(X_train):
        k=np.append(np.array(y_train[i]),j   )
        f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
    f.close()
    f=open('cs-testing.csv','w')
    for i,j in enumerate(X_test):
        k=np.append(np.array(y_test[i]),j   )
        f.write(",".join([str(s) for s in k]) + '\n')
    f.close()


# Convert to one hot
def convertOneHot(data):
    y=np.array([int(i[0]) for i in data])
    y_onehot=[0]*len(y)
    for i,j in enumerate(y):
        y_onehot[i]=[0]*(y.max() + 1)
        y_onehot[i][j]=1
    return (y,y_onehot)


buildDataFromIris()


data = genfromtxt('cs-training.csv',delimiter=',')  # Training data
test_data = genfromtxt('cs-testing.csv',delimiter=',')  # Test data

x_train=np.array([ i[1::] for i in data])
y_train,y_train_onehot = convertOneHot(data)

x_test=np.array([ i[1::] for i in test_data])
y_test,y_test_onehot = convertOneHot(test_data)


#  A number of features, 4 in this example
#  B = 3 species of Iris (setosa, virginica and versicolor)
A=data.shape[1]-1 # Number of features, Note first is y
B=len(y_train_onehot[0])
tf_in = tf.placeholder("float", [None, A]) # Features
tf_weight = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([A,B]))
tf_bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([B]))
tf_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_in,tf_weight) + tf_bias)

# Training via backpropagation
tf_softmax_correct = tf.placeholder("float", [None,B])
tf_cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf_softmax_correct*tf.log(tf_softmax))

# Train using tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
tf_train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(tf_cross_entropy)

# Add accuracy checking nodes
tf_correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_softmax,1), tf.argmax(tf_softmax_correct,1))
tf_accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf_correct_prediction, "float"))

# Initialize and run
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print("...")
# Run the training
for i in range(30):
    sess.run(tf_train_step, feed_dict={tf_in: x_train, tf_softmax_correct: y_train_onehot})

# Print accuracy
    result = sess.run(tf_accuracy, feed_dict={tf_in: x_test, tf_softmax_correct: y_test_onehot})
    print "Run {},{}".format(i,result)


"""
Below is the ouput
  ...
  Run 0,0.319999992847
  Run 1,0.300000011921
  Run 2,0.379999995232
  Run 3,0.319999992847
  Run 4,0.300000011921
  Run 5,0.699999988079
  Run 6,0.680000007153
  Run 7,0.699999988079
  Run 8,0.680000007153
  Run 9,0.699999988079
  Run 10,0.680000007153
  Run 11,0.680000007153
  Run 12,0.540000021458
  Run 13,0.419999986887
  Run 14,0.680000007153
  Run 15,0.699999988079
  Run 16,0.680000007153
  Run 17,0.699999988079
  Run 18,0.680000007153
  Run 19,0.699999988079
  Run 20,0.699999988079
  Run 21,0.699999988079
  Run 22,0.699999988079
  Run 23,0.699999988079
  Run 24,0.680000007153
  Run 25,0.699999988079
  Run 26,1.0
  Run 27,0.819999992847
  ...

 Ref:
 https://gist.github.com/mchirico/bcc376fb336b73f24b29#file-tensorflowiriscsv-py
"""
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have trouble believing that I got a 92.9% accuracy rate on my data using the code you've given me though. The highest scoring person on the challenge only had about an 87.3% accuracy rate.

Comment: Ok what if I'm trying to predict the probability of there being a 0 or 1 and not actually whether it's going to be a 0 or a 1. What I want is to see something like this- .47 it's going to be a 1, .31 that it's going to be a 1, .91 that it's going to be a 1, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Right, so you want probabilities listed for each option. Here's the complete code that will list out the probabilities for the Iris example. [Restore and print all probabilities](https://gist.github.com/mchirico/cce03212eda66e654c54)

Comment: For some reason I keep getting the same probability. 33.33% on everything. It was the same with the 1's and 0's. 92.92%

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide an input matching your x,y_ shape.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 11])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", [None,2])
```

So instead of data.train.next_batch(100) create and use a function "my_csv_batch(count)" which returns an array of shape [[count,11], [count,2]]  The first set of arrays is your x and the next is your y_s labels

my_csv_batch will return a batch (perhaps stochastically generated if you have a lot of data)  from your csv file.

Btw, you'll also need something similar for doing  your eval as well.  You'll have to generate a batch of data and labels similarly.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate a bit on this? I'm still unsure of the [[count, 11], [count, 2]] part. Should I return a batch of only 11 elements within one list? Should I iterate over the array one by one like by using a for loop?

Comment: IT's just a multidimensional python array.  Poppin, you might want to start with a tutorial on python arrays  for example:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/python-array/   One way to ramp on Python is to use the interactive command line prompt (also called a REPL  .. just type python at the command line) and enter in code and see what it does.   It's a great way to learn.

Comment: I still don't understand how that is going to help me out. Can you write out code to help me out? I can't decipher code from your explanation.

Comment: Poppin, I could, but likely you'll just encounter another problem pretty soon which you'll also need help with.  Probably the best thing is to start with the tutorials I linked to above and develop at least a basic understanding before progressing further.

Comment: You're probably right. I should finish the tutorials before I jump into stuff like this. I want to help my coworker with an offering but I need a better understanding.