# Tensorflow 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I also encounter the same problem [Training TensorFlow for Predicting a Column in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789485/training-tensorflow-for-predicting-a-column-in-a-csv-file) which is:

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 1 for i in
>   range(1000): ----> 2 batch_xs, batch_ys = data.train.next_batch(100) 3
>   sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'train'

How do you able to solve it?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

# Import MNIST data
#from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
#mnistt = input_data.read_data_sets("/tttmp/data/", one_hot=True)

from numpy import genfromtxt

import csv
import tensorflow as tf
%matplotlib inline

# Read data...
x_input = genfromtxt('Data_Coffee.csv',delimiter=',')
y_input = genfromtxt('Class_Coffee.csv',delimiter=',')

data=genfromtxt('Data_Coffee.csv',delimiter=',')

matSize = np.shape(data)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1


# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, matSize[0]])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, matSize[1]])

#x= genfromtxt('Data_Coffee.csv',delimiter=',')
#y= genfromtxt('Class_Coffee.csv',delimiter=',')


# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(x.train.num_examples/batch_size)

        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Comment: here `x_input` is just a numpy array. you need to write ur own train data iterator

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate more? Any example and link to follow up? I think i need to feed data to tensorflow, but I am not sure how to do it

Comment: error log quoted

Comment: The error log is: 
    AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'train'

Comment: Isn't the creation of a tensorflow object (one with `train` method) from a numpy array (or arrays) a basic part of a tensorflow documentation or tutorial?  If you've gotten this far in setting up the problem, surely you've encountered instructions on how to create such an object.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the "basic part of a tensorflow documentation or tutorial"? I would like to read back...thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

I think you are copying this pattern from MNIST example: data.train.next_batch

In MNIST example the data is read as an object of a class that has train variable, whereas you are only reading the data as a NumPy array.

Comment: Yes, I am. the original is from MNIST example: mnist.train.next_batch. How can I edit for my data?